# Change notification to different languages

Tags: i18n-l10n, notifications

I have a multilingual website which has English and Chinese as the languages. I use the admin account but i have made a translator account for my chinese colleagues to make translations. Now if i make any changes to the pages in English how can they automatically get notified that they need to update the translation for that specific page. Is there any automatic way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, the module, you need is [Subscriptions](http://drupal.org/project/subscriptions)

The docs say:

> "This module enables users to subscribe to be notified of changes to
>   nodes"

It is actively maintained and was started in 2003.